# System out of range in for loop

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

System is giving me out of range exception when p = 255. My understanding is that with "OR" operator, later part of if statement should come into affect. However, it is not. Please advise on how to fix it.

```cs
for (int p = 0; p < 256; p++)
{
    if (buffer[p] == buffer[p + 1] || buffer[p] == buffer[p - 1])
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the creation of `buffer` and if possible how you populate it.

Comment: "later part of if statement should come into affect" that is wrong, the right side of the "OR" expression only evaluates if the left part is false, if the left side is true, the condition will be true no matter what the right side is.

Comment: If the size of buffer array becomes greater tha 256, you will get this exception.

Comment: @fbede - How can I fix it then??

Comment: @Ezio - I understand that. How can that be fixed as I want to run that logic without getting error.

Comment: does buffer has 256 items? Because if it does then the problem is the left side of the "OR" expression, you are trying to accesss buffer[256] (the 257. item, since indexing starts from zerro) and the buffer only has 256 items.

Comment: `for (int p = 1; p < buffer.Length - 1; p++) {...}`

Comment: @fbede - It does not have 256 items

Comment: then you should start the iteration from index 1 as Dimitry pointed it out

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko - With your solution I will loose data at p=0 in my calculation. Which I cannot afford to loose.

Comment: No you will not, the right side of the expression with p = 1 equals to the left side of the expression with p = 0

Comment: @fbede - Same answer as I gave to Dmitry regarding starting at 1

Comment: @Akshay Sha: you should start from `1`, not `0` otherwise `buffer[p - 1]` will be `buffer[-1]` and you'll get exception thoiwn

Comment: @ fbede @ Dmitry Bychenko - This is my code inside the loop "duplicatePValue = c + "P" + buffer[p];" and by using p=1 I will definately loose data.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration p = 0;
With p = 0; the right side of the conditional expression is trying to access buffer[-1], which throws the Exception.

You should start the iteration with index 1 and end it one item before the last item in the buffer. Try something like this:

```
for (int p = 1; p < buffer.Length - 1; p++)
{
    if (buffer[p] == buffer[p + 1] || buffer[p] == buffer[p - 1])
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? What changes did you make? Why did you make those changes? What is the problem with the original code posted by the OP?

Answer (score 0):

You have *out of range* error. It means that index `p` is out of `buffer` range,
which is

```
// buffer has Length items, starting from 0
[0 .. buffer.Length - 1]
```

Now, let's have a look at index usage: you have

```
if (buffer[p] == buffer[p + 1] || buffer[p] == buffer[p - 1])
```

and you address

1. `buffer[p]` where `p` can be in `0..buffer.Length - 1` range
2. `buffer[p + 1]` where `p` can be in `-1..buffer.Length - 2` range
3. `buffer[p - 1]` where `p` can be in `1..buffer.Length` range

combining all `3` ranges for index `p` together we get `p` in `1..buffer.Length - 2` range or

```
for (int p = 1; p < buffer.Length - 1; p++) 
  if (buffer[p] == buffer[p + 1] || buffer[p] == buffer[p - 1]) {
    ...
  }
```

Note edge cases (first and last `buffer` items):

when `p == 1` we have

```
(buffer[1] == buffer[2] || buffer[1] == buffer[0])
                                               ^
                                               first item
```

when `p == buffer.Length - 2`

```
(buffer[buffer.Length - 2] == buffer[buffer.Length - 1] || buffer[buffer.Length - 2] == buffer[buffer.Length - 3])
                                     ^
                                     last item
```

that's why no item is lost

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing an item x to either the item before it or the item after it. Then you move along one, and you potentially make the same compare you just did, so you're wasting a lot of CPU:

```
var a= new []{1,2,3,4}

if(2 == 1 or 2 == 3)
...
if(3 == 2 or 3 == 4). //3==2 was already done above like 2==3
```

Just compare current with next, moving along by 1 each time, stopping 1 short of the end of the loop

If you want to duplicate messaging, print twice

```
for(int x=0; x<array.Length-1; x++){
  if(array[x] == array[x+1]){
    Console.WriteLine($"index {x} is same as {x+1}");
    Console.WriteLine($"index {x+1} is same as {x}");
  }
}
```

> My understanding is that with "OR" operator, later part of if statement should come into affect.

Later part of statement comes into effect if first part of statement returns false. First part of statement is always done. your first part of statement is guaranteed to crash if the array is length 256

C# isn't some sort of AI that thinks "ooh, if I do the left part of the OR then I'll get a crash, so I'll just do the right part", it just does as you told it according to its "do left, then if false, do right" rules, which might mean you try access an array index that doesn't exist

Worth pointing out that if the first two bytes in your buffer are not the same (left part of OR returns false) then you'll get another crash, this time because C# is trying to evaluate the right side of the OR, and you make it do `buffer[-1]`